# Rails 3.2 One to Many View

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, view, one-to-many

I have tried to get this working, looked at multiple tutorials, questions on here tried different things for about a week now and I can't get the view to work correctly.

I have teams of users. A team **`has_many` users** and a **user `belongs_to` a team** (one team at a time). I know the association works because I got it working using the console (with some help there). I'm not sure how to get it working in the view. Below is the code, please let me know if more is needed.

What am I missing?

**_join_team_button**

```
<%= form_for(@user) do |f| %>
  <%= f.submit "Join Team", class: "btn btn-large btn-primary" %>
<% end %>
```

Team Show Page

```
<%= render 'shared/join_team_button %>
```

Teams Controller

```
def show
  @team =  Team.find(params[:id])
  @team_members = @team.users
  @user = current_user.users.build if signed_in?
end
```

Users Controller

```
def show
  @user = User.find(params[:id])
  @teams = @user.team
end
```

Comment: Is there any method in your `user_controller` that takes a team_id and joins the user to that team? If so add that function here. Run `rake:routes` to see `form_for` will actually point to that method. Also your `form_for` should have a `team_id` otherwise which team the user will be joined?

Comment: The "join_button" will be on the team's show page. I thought the build method should be on the "has_many" part of the association. That's why I have the "@user = current_user.users.build if signed_in?" in the Teams_controller. 

I am basing this off of the microposts relationship from Michael Hartl's tutorial. A user has_many microposts and a microposts belongs_to a user and in my users_controller it says "@micropost = current_user.microposts.build..."

Along those lines, I thought the "id" was picked up automatically. I didn't have to define user.id on the micropost form?

Comment: Hello Steve, didnt hear any update from you... whats the status?

Comment: Hey @samiron I figured it out and got it working. I didn't use exactly what you gave me, but I learned from what you gave me and got it working. Thank you for the help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out. Still not perfect, but it gets the association working. The team, and the user were already created, I just needed to establish the association, so the build method would not have worked.  Here's what I have:

View:

```
<%= form_for(@user) do |f| %>
<%= f.hidden_field :team_id, :value => @team.id %>
  <%= f.submit "Join Team", class: "btn btn-large btn-primary" %>
<% end %>
```

Teams Controller:

```
def show
  @team =  Team.find(params[:id])
  @team_members = @team.users
  @user = User.find(params[:id]) if signed_in?
end
```

Comment: You need to use `hidden_field` to set the `team` id. You url should say that. Follow my example carefully. Another suggestion is to use `link_to` instead of `form_for`. Ive added that too in the view code.

Answer (score 4):

I tried to put a complete demonstration of what you are looking for. Let me know if it fits for you.

```
#FILE: models/team.rb
class Team < AR::Base
   has_many :users
end
```

---

```
#FILE: models/user.rb
class User < AR::Base
   belongs_to :team
end
```

---

```
#FILE: config/routes.rb
#Here you are defining "users" as a nested resource of "teams"
resources :teams  do 
    resources :users do
        member do
            put :join
        end
    end
end

#if you run "rake routes" it will show you the following line along with others
join_team_user PUT    /teams/:team_id/users/:id/join(.:format) users#join
```

---

```
#FILE: controllers/team_controller.rb
def show
    @team =  Team.find(params[:id])
    @team_members = @team.users
    @user = current_user.users.build if signed_in?
end
```

---

```
#FILE: views/teams/show.html.erb
<% if(@user) %>
    <%= form_for @user, :url => join_team_user_path(@team, @user) do |f| %>
      <%= f.submit "Join Team", class: "btn btn-large btn-primary" %>
    <% end %>
<% end %>

#You dont really need a form for this. You can simply use `link_to` like below
<%= link_to 'Join', join_team_user_path(@team, @user), method: :put %>
```

---

```
#FILE: controllers/users_controller.rb
def join
    # params[:id] => is the user_id
    @user = User.find(params[:id])

    # params[:team_id] => is the team_id
    @team = Team.find(params[:team_id])

    # Now make the relationship between user and team here.
    @user.update_attribute(:team, @team)
end
```

---

**Update:***Based on your comment*

***Q:** Do I create a new user's resource and nest that or do I nest the already establishes user's resource?*

**Ans:** Based on your requirements any resource can be defined both independently or nestedly. But yes you can control that which method will be available in which way. Like in your case, you can allow only `join` method when your `user` is nested under `team` resource.

```
resources :users, :only=>:join do
    member do
        put :join
    end
end
resource :users
```

run `rake routes` with and without `:only=>:join` option and see differences in available routes.

***Q:** Will that affect other things?*

**Ans:** If you strictly define your routes following above example, it should not affect other things. You should confirm all the available routes to your application by `rake routes`.

***Q:** Should I put my current `routes.rb` file up there?*

**Ans:** Assuming your current `routes.rb` will be modified in the above way. Could I answer the question?

***Q:** Confused about the comments controller?*

**Ans:** Im extreamely sorry. Yes it must be `users_controller.rb` as the `rake routes` command is showing. Result of copy and paste from my own example code :P

***Q:** what should I put there? the build method*

**Ans:** In your case both the `user` and `team` is already exists in your database. All you need to do is just setup a relationship. So you can just use `update_attribute` option. Ive changed the join method. Please check. But yes if want to create new entries you might need build methods.

*Sorry for the late reply :)*

Comment: @samiron-paul Thanks for your answer. I just have a couple questions before I accept it. It makes sense to me, but I already have a user resource and a user will have a choice to join a team or not (they don't have to)

Do I create a new user's resource and nest that or do I nest the already establishes user's resource? Will that affect other things?

Should I put my current routes.rb file up there?

Confused about the comments controller? Should that be team's or user's controller and what should I put there? the build method?